# Magento2 unfriendly urls after import products

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite

I've imported products with the build in importer. 
Since then a lot of products are only reachable via the long url's.

http://domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/295/s/product-name/category/4/

But when i check in the backend both as default value as for the storeview a url key is filled in. (also in the url's "product-name" element)

tried re-indexing, refreshing cache. but no result. when adding a product by hand we do not seem to have this issue.

Update: 28 jul 2016:
After a lot of trying things out, there is still a issue with this. 
I did a clean install of 2.1
After playing around i got all urls working (import / exporting and so on)
A huge issue was that the urls where not added to the main store but only to the store view)

Anyone more experience with this issue?

Creating the url by hand in the backend (marketing->url management) seem to solve it. but thats horrible work.

Edit, i have found some more information. 
We have a site with multiple storeviews, i notice that our first store has problems with the url. when i search the url key in the url_rewrite database i do find the url for all store's (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) excpect for store. 1.

Should't there be a store 0 url key ??

Comment: is your reindex process completed successfully using command line?

Comment: @User34444 yes done that indeed, and thats not the issue

Comment: You can show your sample csv?

Comment: Did you add Products to correct stores (store_id ) in your CSV.

Comment: @ForgeOnline We tried it with a specific store_code and without.

Answer (score 0):

You have imported product, but you have not created url_key for all product magento uses 301 redirect rule try to add url_key as well and try again

Comment: Sorry thats not correct. as you can see in my description. i both tried it with and without filled in url key

Answer (score 0):

Following extension will help you to regenerate all url_key

> https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites